# csv to json, can't encode output correctly

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
// file: nl.csv
One;Eén
Two;Twee
Three;Drie
```

This file is created with Excel.

With PHP, I want to create a new js file from this csv file, in the following style:

```
// file: nl.js
export const nl = {
    One: "Eén",
    Two: "Twee",
    Three: "Drie"
}
```

So far so good, I managed to create a PHP function to read a csv file and parse it as a js file:

```
<?php
$language = 'nl';
$csv = file($file.'.csv');
$data = array();
foreach($cvs as $line){
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line, ';');
}
$handle = fopen($language.'.js', 'w');
fwrite($handle, "export const {$language} = {\n");
foreach($data as $line){
    $key = $line[0];
    $value = $line[1];
    fwrite($handle, "\t{$key}: \"{$value}\",\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "}");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

The problem is with the encoding: in the first line, there is a 'é' in the text. And this is not correctly converted, I get a black square with a white question mark in it.

When I check the encoding of every line, I get the following output:

```
// function
mb_detect_encoding($line)

// output
UTF-8 // first line with 'é'
ASCII // second line
ASCII // third line
```

I don't want to replace the 'é' with `&eacute;`, I just want the 'é' to be "hardcoded" in my file. When I manually change all the black squares in my json file to 'é', it works.

What I did so far:

```
// adding htmlspeciarchars
$data[] = str_getcsv(htmlspecialchars($line), ';');
// the first line does not get output, the other lines do

// adding htmlentities
$data[] = str_getcsv(htmlentities($line), ';');
// same as with htmlspecialchars()
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: 1) Don't manually create JSON/Javascript; build an array and `json_encode` it. 2) What encoding does Excel output? Open it in a text editor using "Open using encoding…" (or whatever your text editor calls it) until you find the encoding that interprets it correctly. 3) If completely in doubt, use a hex editor to look at the encoded bytes and show us.

Comment: Since `mb_detect_encoding` already gives you *UTF-8*, it appears there may be nothing wrong here per se, and the problem may be entirely how you handle the produced .js file from here on…

Comment: Let me guess, the character encoding of the excel is windows-1252, but your php script handles UTF-8

Comment: I dont see how you've gotten anywhere with this line `foreach($cvs as $line)`... Shouldn't that be `$csv`?